# Consuming rabbitmq queue from inside python threads

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq

This is a long one.

I have a list of usernames and passwords. For each one I want to login to the accounts and do something things. I want to use several machines to do this faster. The way I was thinking of doing this is have a main machine whose job is just having a cron which from time to time checks if the rabbitmq queue is empty. If it is, read the list of usernames and passwords from a file and send it to the rabbitmq queue. Then have a bunch of machines which are subscribed to that queue whose job is receiving a user/pass, do stuff on it, acknowledge it, and move on to the next one, until the queue is empty and then the main machine fills it up again. So far I think I have everything down.

Now comes my problem. I have checked that the things to be done with each user/passes aren't so intensive and so I could have each machine doing three of them simultaneously using python's threading. In fact for a single machine I have implemented this where I load the user/passes into a python Queue() and then have three threads consume that Queue(). Now I want to do something similar, but instead of consuming from a python Queue(), each thread of each machine should consume from a rabbitmq queue. This is where I'm stuck. To run tests I started by using rabbitmq's tutorial.

send.py:

```
import pika, sys
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

message = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body=message)
connection.close()
```

worker.py

```
import time, pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print ' [x] received %r' % (body,)
    time.sleep( body.count('.') )
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='hello', no_ack=False)
channel.start_consuming()
```

For the above you can run two worker.py which will subscribe to the rabbitmq queue and consume as expected.

My threading without rabbitmq is something like this:

runit.py

```
class Threaded_do_stuff(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, user_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.user_queue = user_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            login = self.user_queue.get()
            do_stuff(user=login[0], pass=login[1])
            self.user_queue.task_done()

user_queue = Queue.Queue()
for i in range(3):
    td = Threaded_do_stuff(user_queue)
    td.setDaemon(True)
    td.start()

## fill up the queue
for user in list_users:
    user_queue.put(user)

## go!
user_queue.join()
```

This also works as expected: you fill up the queue and have 3 threads subscribe to it. Now what I want to do is something like runit.py but instead of using a python Queue(), using something like worker.py where the queue is actually a rabbitmq queue.

Here's something which I tried and didn't work (and I don't understand why)

rabbitmq_runit.py

```
import time, threading, pika

class Threaded_worker(threading.Thread):
    def callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        print ' [x] received %r' % (body,)
        time.sleep( body.count('.') )
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
        self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        self.channel.basic_consume(self.callback, queue='hello')

    def run(self):
        print 'start consuming'
        self.channel.start_consuming()

for _ in range(3):
    print 'launch thread'
    td = Threaded_worker()
    td.setDaemon(True)
    td.start()
```

I would expect that this launches three threads each of which is blocked by .start_consuming() which just stays there waiting for the rabbitmq queue to send them sometihing. Instead, this program starts, does some prints, and exits. The pattern of the exists is weird too:

```
launch thread
launch thread
start consuming
launch thread
start consuming
```

In particular notice there is one "start consuming" missing.

What's going on?

EDIT: One answer I found to a similar question is here
[Consuming a rabbitmq message queue with multiple threads (Python Kombu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504005/consuming-a-rabbitmq-message-queue-with-multiple-threads-python-kombu)
and the answer is to "use celery", whatever that means. I don't buy it, I shouldn't need anything remotely as sophisticated as celery. In particular, I'm not trying to set up an RPC and I don't need to read replies from the do_stuff routines.

EDIT 2: The print pattern that I expected would be the following. I do

```
python send.py first message......
python send.py second message.
python send.py third message.
python send.py fourth message.
```

and the print pattern would be

```
launch thread
start consuming
 [x] received 'first message......'
launch thread
start consuming
 [x] received 'second message.'
launch thread
start consuming
 [x] received 'third message.'
 [x] received 'fourth message.'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you're making the thread daemonic:

```
td = Threaded_worker()
td.setDaemon(True)  # Shouldn't do that.
td.start()
```

Daemonic threads will be terminated [as soon as the main thread exit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects)s:

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this
>   flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads
>   are left. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The
>   flag can be set through the daemon property.

Leave out `setDaemon(True)` and you should see it behave the way you expect.

Also, the [pika FAQ](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#frequently-asked-questions) has a note about how to use it with threads:

> Pika does not have any notion of threading in the code. If you want to
>   use Pika with threading, make sure you have a Pika connection per
>   thread, created in that thread. It is not safe to share one Pika
>   connection across threads.

This suggests you should move everything you're doing in `__init__()` into `run()`, so that the connection is created in the same thread you're actually consuming from the queue in.

Comment: That's it! Amazing, I didn't expect anyone would read such a long post, let along be able to answer it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also for completeness: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html, chapters "Channels" and "Connections": it would be better to have one channel per thread and share the connection, but pika does not support it.